# UnsupportedOperationException in DSS server

Tags: wso2

I am getting below exception when I try to connect DSS server to mssql 2008 r2. I have already added the `sqljdbc4.jar` file to `wso2dss-3.0.1\repository\components\lib`. Anyway still I am getting below error:

```
SEVERE: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.6 is not supported by this driver.
        Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
[2013-09-17 19:40:38,790] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver}
-  Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.6 is not supported by this driver. 
Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library,
```

Answer (score 0):

sqljdbc4.jar class library requires JRE version to be 6.0 or later. So sqljdbc4.jar needs to be used when your java version is 1.6 or above. If your java version is 1.5 or less use sqljdbc.jar. You can download sqljdbc.jar here, http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqljdbcjar.htm

Comment: java version is 1.6

C:\Documents and Settings\aruna>java -version
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode, sharing)